# How do I associate makis in a custom style with a poi-label in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox

I am creating in Mapbox Studio a style from scratch. I have a poi-label layer that filters by data. I can see the filter works. I can place a text label at the location of the poi, all in Mapbox Studio.

For the life of it I cannot show an icon with the text. I have tried to paste a some_maki.svg from the Maki iconset in to the "Icon image" field. THe cursor indicates that pasting is a valid operation, the image is uploaded, but it does not show on the map. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Maki icon set](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) provides each icon in two SVG sizes: 11px by 11px and 15px by 15px. So, when you use the name of a particular Maki icon in the [`'icon-image'`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-image) layout property, you also need to append the icon's name with either `-11` or `-15`.

For example, consider the `'icon-image'` for the `poi-label` layer in the default Mapbox Street style when inspected in Mapbox Studio:

[image]

So, if you include `& "-11"` or `& "-15"` in your icon image formula, and the referenced icon is included in your style's [sprite](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/sprite/) sheet, the icons should show up as expected. You can add and remove image's in your style's sprite with the image toolbar, as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/styles/#images-toolbar).